# Make apexcharts-inner take up full space

Tags: apexcharts, radar-chart

On the image below I have highlighted the whole chart, but I would like the radar to take up the full height of the whole chart (so no space is left) I have tried
*chart: {
type: 'radar',
height: '400px',
},*
but it just set the whole chart to a specific height and still leaves the space. I also tried css, but I can't set the height of a  element

[The whole chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjN2C.png)